# Radio button: attribute that it is automatically selected

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I want a radio button to be automatically selected every time it is open in the screen. so that the user will no longer click it. what attribute will i use?

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Choose<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add checked

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Choose<br>
```

To hide the radio button use below css:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: how do i hide the radio button icon?

Comment: @user3630809 see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

checked attribute used to set your radio button or checked box to pre-selected state while page is loaded.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Choose</br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked='checked'>Choose<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male</br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</br>
```

Click [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/S222H/) for the working example on jsFiddle.

Hope this helps